# Bypass Sda3_crypt in Recovery mode

Tags: encryption, data-recovery

it began when I am trying to install something through the terminal until my root password is not working. It gave me an error saying incorrect password even though it's the right one. Tried signing out of my account then my account was locked forced to reboot. Now I can't boot my laptop since my password for sda3 has been changed as well. I also tried recovery mode but sadly it requires my sda3 pass which unfortunately got changed along with my root and account password.

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Favour returned!  Question upvoted!  You're an 8 rep user already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### With great security comes great responsibility.

If you don't remember the password for the encrypted partition of your computer, *nothing in the world* can recover it for you.  (Not even the NSA)

So remove the HDD, keep it around for the next 20-30 years and maybe then we'll have quantum computers that will be able to decrypt your data...

Until then?  *Sorry!*

Comment: "s you've never"? Surely that should be an "As"? **;-)**

Comment: :P  @ParanoidPanda

Comment: Sigh rookie mistake I guess. Welp better wipeout my drive then I guess? Thanks for the response though. 

Comment: @JioM. Sorry...